# How to write a Cordova plugin with SwiftUI

Tags: swift, cordova, swiftui, cordova-plugins, qr-code

I am writing a QR code scanning cordova iOS plugin. I want to use [this swift package](https://github.com/twostraws/CodeScanner/tree/main/Sources/CodeScanner).

Right now I am experimenting by editing the code from [this tutorial](https://simonprickett.dev/writing-a-cordova-plugin-in-swift-for-ios/)

Below is my code:

```swift
import SwiftUI

@available(iOS 13.0, *)
@objc(ModusEchoSwift) class ModusEchoSwift : CDVPlugin {

  @objc(echo:)
  func echo(command: CDVInvokedUrlCommand) {

    let ui = Button(

      action: {

        let pluginResult = CDVPluginResult(
          status: CDVCommandStatus_OK,
          messageAs: "Successful"
        )

        self.commandDelegate!.send(
          pluginResult,
          callbackId: command.callbackId
        )
      },
      label: {
        Text("Click me")
      }
    );

  }
}
```

I am now stuck on how to display the interface created in Swift.

Comment: giving the rule the command of the entire nato army to Julius Caesar... Why Cordova and SwiftUI?

Comment: @grandsirr Because the entire app was already written in Cordova (hence Cordova), and because the plugin needs to have a UI (hence SwiftUI)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I found this to work:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

@available(iOS 13.0, *)
@objc(ModusEchoSwift) class ModusEchoSwift : CDVPlugin {

  var hostingViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: ExampleView())

  @objc(echo:)
  func echo(command: CDVInvokedUrlCommand) {

    lazy var hostingViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: ExampleView(
      callbackId: command.callbackId,
      module: self
    ));

    self.viewController.show(hostingViewController, sender: self);
    self.hostingViewController = hostingViewController;

  }
}


@available(iOS 13.0, *)
struct ExampleView: View {

  var callbackId: String?
  var module: ModusEchoSwift?
        
  var body: some View {

    VStack {

      Spacer()

      Text("Example")

      Button {
        let pluginResult = CDVPluginResult(
          status: CDVCommandStatus_OK,
          messageAs: "Successful"
        );

        module!.commandDelegate!.send(
          pluginResult,
          callbackId: callbackId!
        );

        module!.hostingViewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil);

      } label: {
          Text("Close Me")
            .padding()
      }

      Spacer()

    }
  }
}
```

I'm pretty sure that there is a better way of doing this, and I appreciate more answers from you guys.